# Integrating nifi receiverwith Spark streaming causes sbt assembly to fail

Tags: apache-spark, sbt, spark-streaming, sbt-assembly, apache-nifi

I'm trying to create a Spark Streaming application using a nifi receiver. According to a tutorial, I added the sbt dependancies to my build file, but now `sbt assembly` is failing with a deduplicate error.

My build.sbt file is:

```
version := "0.0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.5"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.10" % "1.6.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.10" % "1.6.1" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.nifi" % "nifi-spark-receiver" % "0.6.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.nifi" % "nifi-site-to-site-client" % "0.6.1"
```

And the error I'm getting is:

```
[error] (*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] org.apache.avro\avro-ipc\jars\avro-ipc-1.7.7-tests.jar:META-INF/maven/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/pom.properties
[error] org.apache.avro\avro-ipc\jars\avro-ipc-1.7.7.jar:META-INF/maven/org.apache.avro/avro-ipc/pom.properties
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Thanks,
Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure if this is the problem, but recently someone pointed out that the nifi-spark-receiver should have a "provided" dependency on Spark, otherwise it could cause problems on the classpath.

It was addressed in this JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-1803 which will be released in the next 0.x release of NiFi (or 1.0 if there isn't an 0.7).

You could try building your own copy of NiFi from the 0.x branch using mvn install, and then try using the 0.7.0-SNAPSHOT of nifi-spark-receiver which would be available in your local Maven repo.